# Try/exception command in while loop (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, try-catch

I am trying to create a function that extracts a batch of patients in a given directory of CT scans. Some patients' scans fail during image segmentation, so I am looping over the list until I find the "batch number" of patients with successful segmentation. However, the code below loops infinitely when I run it. I do not understand why the 'break' does not terminate the loop.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!:)

```
INPUT_FOLDER = "D:\CT\stage1\stage1"

patients = os.listdir(INPUT_FOLDER)
patients.sort()

#start, n_batch are given as parameters.

data = start    #initialize index for list 'validation_patients'
valid_patient_list = []   #create an empty list for patient data with successful segmentation

while True:   #iterate over variable 'data' until the list of valid patients is completed

    try:
        x = patients[data]
        load_scan(INPUT_FOLDER + '\\' + x)
        valid_patient_list.append(data)

        if len(valid_patient_list) == n_batch:  #escape while loop when the list length is equal to designated batch size

            break

        else: data += 1 #if the length of list is smaller than the desired batch number, go for the next patient

    except IndexError: 
        data += 1 # go for the next data: do not add this one to the list
        continue

#some more code below that deals with the valid_patient_list, but the loop runs infinitely..
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend you make your error handling more specific and add some feedback - at the moment it's impossible for you (or anyone else) to see what precisely is going wrong.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for your comment. I added a comment to make my purpose more explicit. What I'm trying to do here is picking a batch of patients from a list of hundreds of patient data. I could just iterate over the batches in order, but that doesn't work, because some of the patients have data that do not work. I am using the try/exception command to deal with that problem. Sorry, I'm relatively new to python, so I'm not sure if this answers your question.

Comment: I didn't ask a question. I'm suggesting you do more debugging - see e.g. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

Well if you get an IndexError on patients[data], it is because data >= len(patients), an index out of range error, so patients[data+1] will also raise an IndexErorr.

This causes your code to go to an infinite loop between raising and catching exceptions, and the code never reaches the 'break' part.